# Fastest way to replace string in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-encode

When I submit/POST data to the server, I need to *HTMLencode* its characters (the relevant ones), since disabling input check by setting `validationRequest = false` is **not** a good practice.

All solutions are *finally* replacing chars in string:

This is what i've written.

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\&/g, "&amp;");
    str = str.replace(/\</g, "&lt;");
    str = str.replace(/\>/g, "&gt;");
    str = str.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
    return str;
}
```

But apprently regex could be replaced with something much faster (don't get me wrong - I love regex).

Also, working with indexes + sub-strings seems wasteful.

What is the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: *disabling input check by setting validationRequest = false - is not a good practice* — Hacking around a security filter that rejects data you want to accept is worse practise. Set up your security filters to access the type of content you want to accept instead of accepting defaults designed to protect people who don't know what they are doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding (edit: @ammoQ - heh!)

Comment: @Quentin it is not recommanded http://books.google.co.il/books?id=QJNoykS0Tv4C&pg=PT84&lpg=PT84&dq=%22Another+approach+you+could+take+is+to+disable+request%22&source=bl&ots=JNalmbHtnV&sig=TFAcCLdRkgzHJMWsE7fzd5pWCtA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5CdgULq0FLPI0AXi2oGICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Another%20approach%20you%20could%20take%20is%20to%20disable%20request%22&f=false from asp.net security book

Comment: @RoyiNamir — That says it is a bad idea to turn it off "site-wide" not "when you need it". First it tells you how to do it on a page-by-page basis, then it tells you it is a bad idea to do it site-wide, then it tells you how to do it site wide.

Comment: @Quentin looking at fiddler on SO and facebook - they do heml encode it before submit

Comment: @gdoron yeah. thats distinguish good programmer to excellent programmer.

Comment: @RoyiNamir — Just edited one of my answers (and added `<` and `>` characters). No sign of any HTML encoding in the submitted data.

Comment: @RoyiNamir — Good/Great programmers don't micro-optimise until code profiling says they need to. They write code designed to maximise maintainability.

Comment: @Quentin regex replace wont give best performance. which will do ? Thats my question

Comment: @RoyiNamir — Not HTML encoding on the client in the first place will give the best performance on the client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

[**jsperf tests show**](http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex) this method is fast and possibly the fastest option if you're in a recent browser version

anothre way to also like this

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Comment: this wont handle multi space.

Comment: This works for most scenarios, but this implementation of htmlDecode will eliminate any extra whitespace. So for some values of "input", input != htmlDecode(htmlEncode(input)). This was a problem for us in some scenarios. For example, if input = "<p>\t Hi \n There </p>", a roundtrip encode/decode will yield "<p> Hi There </p>

Comment: i think get text and `trim()` function will help you. or my be ` .replace(/  /g, ' ')`

Comment: I had to replace &#39; with &apos; for apostrophes to avoid the .net "potentially dangerous" error.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just encoding HTML entities, you can try:

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    var d = document.createElement('b');
    d.innerText = str;
    return d.innerHTML;
}
```

This way is not *the fastest*. This test indicates that regExp is faster: http://jsperf.com/encodehtml

However, the difference seems to be smaller the more HTML you consume.

The innerText method seems more reliable as it will exploit the native browser conversion tables for entities. With RegExp, there is always a chance that you missed something and as some [previous answers indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/210578), consuming HTML using RegExp is not always optimal.

Comment: see my comment to Champ. same here

Comment: Yes, it’s worth noting that this method returns the browser implementation of innerText, so \n becomes <br> etc. If you need explicit control over each character, RegExp is probably better.

Answer (score -1):

```
function htmlEncode(value){
    if (value) {
        return jQuery('<div />').text(value).html();
    }
    return '';
}
 
function htmlDecode(value) {
    if (value) {
        return $('<div />').html(value).text();
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: This works for most scenarios, but this implementation of htmlDecode will eliminate any extra whitespace. So for some values of "input", input != htmlDecode(htmlEncode(input)). This was a problem for us in some scenarios. For example, if input = "<p>\t Hi \n There </p>", a roundtrip encode/decode will yield "<p> Hi There </p>